# how to access the array declared in codebehind from javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, code-behind

i am having the code like the following

```
Public cs As ClientScriptManager

Public Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    cs = Page.ClientScript

    cs.RegisterArrayDeclaration("activArray", """asd"",""ert"",""sdt""")

End Sub


//"text/javascript"

function doInit() {

        alert(activArray.length)
}
```

while running these code,it shows an error
**Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'activArray' is undefined**

Please help me to solve this error.Thank you

Comment: Maybe the doInit() JS function is defined before the the activeArray, you could look at the HTML source code to check

Comment: i tried inside other functions also. There also giving same error.

Comment: Could you post the HTML source code for the page?

Comment: hello Xharze, i tried the following,also gives same error 

<html>
<head runat="server">
<script language ="javascript" type ="text/javascript">
    function setActivity() {
        
        alert(Skills.length)
    }
</script>
    
</head>
<body>
    <input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" onclick="setActivity();"/>
</body>
</html>

Public Class test
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        Page.ClientScript.RegisterArrayDeclaration("Skills", "'hel','wo'")
       

    End Sub

End Class

Comment: Do you have a form tag on the page? With attribute runat="server"?

Comment: hello Xharze
    i get this done by using ClientScriptManager and RegisterStartupScript... generated javascript itself by using codebehind...
thank You

Answer (score -2):

Just use `\` to escape the array string like:

```
cs.RegisterArrayDeclaration("activArray", "\"asd\","\"ert\","\"sdt\"")
```

Comment: VB does not use `\` escape characters, like `c` or `c#`.